# Client module for communication with server

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, client-server, n-tier-architecture

How to call it properly?

There are two apps, client and server, that interacts with each other using some protocol. I try to perform functional decomposition of these apps, and choose names for each architectural tier/level.

Comment: I need to find a name of client application module that is responsible to communication with server. That's all. Only a good suitable name. I consider "server iterface", "client controller", "server module" or something similar but I want to know some conventional words for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The description is quite poor and unclear. It'll be better to edit your question and add more information, so people can help you and can provide useful information.

The first think that come in mind is [Multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). Since its a client–server architecture in which presentation, application processing, and data management functions are separated. The most widespread use of multi-tier architecture is the [three-tier](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24649/three-tier-architecture) architecture.

Update:

If we consider the [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern), you can adapt it in such manner:

- Server (Receiver / CommandReceiver)
- Client (CommandApplication)
- Applications (Invoker)

All your class names are quite good and descriptive. More important is to keep the concept.

Or you can search real-life examples and choose more suitable/preferable for your design name.
Like in [this implementation](http://www.journaldev.com/1624/command-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) :

```
public class FileSystemClient {
......
}
```

Comment: Added a comment to original question. Saw these links, descriptions are very high-level, none of them contains appropriate names for feature I described.